# How to set buttons to the bottom of screen with Linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I just started with Android and have the following code. I want to show the three buttons at the bottom of the screen without changing to a Relative layout. I tried setting the `layout_weight` and `gravity` of the inner linear layout but this puts the buttons to the bottom, behind the three menu buttons of the phone. How can I show them above the menu buttons? Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_box"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/search_box" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="80dp"
        android:text="@string/welcome"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/buttonB1" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/buttonB2" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/buttonB3" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Left image shows the buttons I want to move to the bottom. Right image shows my attempt to do so but the buttons end up partially behind the system menu buttons.

[image: Buttons I want to move to the bottom]
[image: Buttons behind the menu buttons of phone]

Comment: Why not use a relative layout? It will save you a ton of time and effort.

Comment: Did you try running this on a device? I wonder if it is just the preview screen displaying incorrect results.

Comment: Well the image he posted clearly isn't the preview but emulator.

Comment: @Vucko I disagree. Not sure how you think you can say it is clearly running in an emulator.

Comment: You got the point, it is a preview. Dunno where my eyes have been lookin :D

Comment: I just copied your layout and ran it in an emulator. Got this: http://i.imgur.com/com1SSu.png

Comment: Yeah it's the preview pane :)

Comment: I ran it on bluestacks and it shows up correctly (however it doesn't have the menu buttons). Had no idea the preview and running version would differ.  Should have checked earlier. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a margin on the bottom of each of your buttons. Add this to each button layout: android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"

If that doesn't work, add a bottom margin to the linearlayout itself.

Comment: It works but running on emulator, it adds additional space below the buttons. Wanted to have them on the edge of screen.

Answer (score 0):

set TextView height = 0, weight = 1. 
And LinearLayout height = wrap content.
It will be OK. Try !

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_box"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/search_box" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#F00"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="80dp"
        android:text="@string/welcome"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FF0"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/buttonB1" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/buttonB2" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/buttonB3" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```